# How can I do Laplace transform of multivariable function?

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

[image]

How can I do the Laplace transform of the above function? Can anyone help me to figure it out?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: It is not a multivariable function - there is only one variable $t$. On the other hand, it is a *convolution* - good time to check the properties of the Laplace transform.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: A simple case to start with (which can serve as a check): when $\alpha_i+\beta_i = 0$ then all the exponentials go away and you are left with integrating "1" $2k$ times to get $t^{2k}/(2k)!$ (times the constant $\alpha_1\alpha_2^{2k-1}$). Laplace transforming this is easy (the integral is basically just the definition of the Gamma function). To do it in general notice that, as suggested above, $f = (P_1f_1)*(\lambda_2f_2)*\ldots (\lambda_2f_2) * (\lambda_1f_1)$ and recall the convolution theorem. Use the special case I mentioned above to check your answer.

Comment: @Winther Thank you for your answer. Then, does that mean it is okay for me to do Laplace transforms for each integrand and multiply them?

Comment: That is pretty much it. But to be precise: its not of every integrand, but of every function being convolved (e.g. $f(t) = \int g(x) h(t-x)dx$ then $L(f) = L(g)L(h)$ which is relevant for the last integrand).